There is an error in vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php at line: 253
I am upgrading the Magento version from 2.2.3 to 2.4.7-p2. After successfully running the composer update command, I encountered the following error when running the setup:upgrade command.
There is an error in /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php at line: 253
Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder::processTable(): Return value must be of type Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Table, bool returned#0 /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php(150): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder->processTable()
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/SchemaConfig.php(78): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\SchemaBuilder->build()
#2 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/DeclarationInstaller.php(57): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\SchemaConfig->getDeclarationConfig()
#3 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(868): Magento\Setup\Model\DeclarationInstaller->installSchema()
#4 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(916): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->declarativeInstallSchema()
#5 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(147): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema()
#6 /vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute()
#7 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1078): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#8 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(324): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(118): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#10 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(175): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#11 /bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#12 {main}


After debugging, I found the issue is related to some default Magento tables. The affected tables are as follows:
catalog_category_product_index_store1

